# live link checking with Python can't get it to run from file

Tags: python

I have written a script that checks to see is a link is live on a website, in this case 'twitter.com'

I can appreciate the way I have done this is probably not the best but I am pretty new to Python and programming in general.

Anyway I am trying to run this from a file of links so the raw input of one URL would be done away with and I would be running multiple URL checks from a file to see if they contained 'twitter.com'

Here is my code, working but using raw_input()

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

link_list = []

status = ' Live!!'

domain = 'twitter.com'

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")


r  = requests.get('http://www.' +url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links = (link.get('href'))
    link_list.append(links)


if domain in ', '.join(link_list):
    print url +status
```

Just to clarify I have a file of URLS, line by line and I'd like to check if they contain 'twitter.com'

I have tried many ways but it just won't work!!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a file and read the lines into an array, it's easy:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    urls = f.readlines()
```

After that, `urls` will be a list of the names.

Then you can iterate over this list:

```
for url in urls:
    link_list = []
    r  = requests.get('http://www.' +url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links = (link.get('href'))
        link_list.append(links)

    if domain in ', '.join(link_list):
        print url +status
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, I actually tried exactly that and I get an error. I tried your exact example just to be sure and I'm still getting an error. Did you manage to get that to run?